# How can I render a child component or parallel component when a state is set in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

How can I render a child component or parallel component when a state is set?

Main component contains the following code

```
editValue(data) {
  console.log("edited")
  this.setState({ edits:data }, function() {
    console.log("edited value...")
  })
}
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <TextComponent edit={this.editValue.bind(this)}/>  
      <AreaComponent editedValue = {this.state.edits}/> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

**TextComponent:**

```
trigger = (data) => {
  this.props.edit(data)
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={this.trigger.bind(this,'clicked')}>Click</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**AreaComponent:**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update - component")
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('receive - component');
}
```

Here when I click the `<p>` I got my console as following

```
edited
receive - component
update - component
edited value...
```

What my issue is the edited value that I set in state is not reflecting in my `AreaComponent`. All the `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` are triggered before setting the state. I want to get the state value inside my next component. What changes should I do in this code?

Comment: The child liofecycle method are not triggered before state is set, instead the callback to setState is triggered after the child lifecycle method are called. Also how are you checking that the state has not updated and and how are you passing data to the editValue componet

Comment: The state is updated but only after the re-rendering of the components. I got this by checking the console values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misInterpreting the console results, you have looged `edited value..` in the `setState callback` which is triggered after the component has updated due to a state change.

If you actually look into the `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidUpdate` of childComponent and log the props in these lifecycle or as a matter of fact in render method  you could actually see the updated value that you set in state.

You should think of `setState callback` as a `lifecycle` which is triggered after component updates similar to `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` of parent is triggered after `componentDidUpdate` of child components most often

Answer (score 1):

Hey I tested out your code and it functions as you expected.

Here's a sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/7yry1onrq6

In order for you to see the changes after you click `TextComponent` just use the `editedValue` prop in the `AreaComponent`.

This is an example mirroring your code:

```
class AreaComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update - component");
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("receive - component");
  }
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.editedValue}</p>;
  }
}
```

In the above example the `editedValue` is correctly changing after clicking.